# iOS app never exits the map

Tags: ios, dictionary, load

My app is just uploaded on the app store. In my app I have a button that gives direction to a specific location from the current location. In the simulator everything works fine, but on the iphone when the button is taped it loads the map, and so you would press the iphone button to exit the map but when I tap on my app to open it again, it loads the map again even after an hour!

basically it keeps loading the map when the app is loaded every time after the direction button is pressed.

so you open the app and the app only opens the map!

I have no idea what's going on!

here is the code I used,

```
- (IBAction)directionButton {
[super viewDidLoad];

CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
double currentLat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double currentLong = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",
                 currentLat, 
                 currentLong,
                 [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
```

Comment: Always test on real hardware before releasing an app to the app store.   The simulator is not perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. when you are done updating the location call the following method,

```
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

where manager is your instance of CLLocationManager.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't call [super viewDidload] in - (IBAction)directionButton method.
2. I think you call - (IBAction)directionButton method somewhere in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear or like that methods. So each time you open your application this methods are called and after a while when CLLocationManager calls delegate method your app redirects to Maps app.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but from what I understand, it is simply a matter of dismissing the view containing the map and returning to the previous view. How are you changing the view from the view with the button to the view with the map?

Comment: That should open the maps app on the device, which is a completely separate application

Comment: exactly! I don't know why it does that!

Comment: is there anyway to make the app load the first page every time it's opened?

Comment: The 'first page'? In your app, what actually triggers the opening of google maps?

Comment: I think I got it. I'm going to prevent the application from running on the background. this should solve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this by preventing the app from running on the background.

so you would need to add a new row to your info.plist and make it "Application does not run in background", have the box in front of it checked.

Comment: That was my guess, but it's not clear if it's a good thing or not. If you don't run in the background, then I wouldn't be able to check my email, then go back to the directions.

Comment: last solution I would go to